# How can I assign the value of a Map Key to a string in groovy

Tags: groovy, hashmap, key

I have written a method (mentioned below) which returns a Map.

```
Class MyTest
static Map<String, String> getApplicationPreferences() {
    String host = System.getProperty("property1")
    String namespace = System.getProperty("property2")
    String username = System.getProperty("property3")
    String password = System.getProperty("property4")
    String url = "http://" + host + ":10000/v3/namespaces/" + namespace + "/apps/MyApplication/preferences"
    String token = RestUtil.getToken(host, username, password)
    HttpURLConnection connection = RestUtil.sendRequest(url, token, true, RestUtil.REQUEST_METHOD.GET)
    String response = connection.getInputStream().getText()
    Map<String, String> preferences = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, Map.class)
    return preferences
}
```

I am calling the above method as:

```
static Map<String, String> envPreferences = new HashMap<String, String>();
envPreferences = MyTest.getApplicationPreferences()
```

and printing the Values from the Map by following way:

```
println("\nAll preferences="+envPreferences.toString()+"\n")
```

Now I want to assign the values to String variables which I have to pass to another function.

```
static String a = envPreferences.get('messaging.kafkaBrokers')
println("Kafka preferences="+a)

static String b = envPreferences.get("zookeeper.server").toString()
println("Zookeeper preferences="+b)
```

The Output that I am getting for the above print statements are:

```
All preferences=[zookeeper.server:localhost:2181, messaging.kafkaBrokers:localhost:9092]
Kafka preferences=null
Zookeeper preferences="null"
```

How can I get the values instead of null?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is a bit "javaish" (instead of groovyish), but in general this is how you would get the value for that string out of the map.  So one explanation here could be, that whatever the keys in those maps are, they print like a string, but they are not. You could try to `println(envPreferences.inspect())` or ask the keys for their type (or use a debugger). One thing that concerns me are the discrepancies between the output and your prints.  E.g. `Zookeeper preferences="null"` would indicate that the value for `zookeeper.server` is '"null"'.  Are those CnP errors?

Comment: the strange for me that `envPreferences` declared as `static` and initialized with empty map. And i'm not sure it's assigned in static context `envPreferences = MyTest.getApplicationPreferences()`. we don't see the full picture. could you provide the script or class where `envPreferences` declared and used...

Comment: There is a lot of code and it's unclear what particular problem did you face.

Could you provide a minimal reproducible example and clarify what exactly are you having problems with?